# Is the set $A = \{(X,|X|) : X \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_5\}$ a function? If so, what is its domain and range?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I know this is a function because the inputs don't share the same outputs and it passes the vertical line test.

What I did was to find what $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is? it is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and this is my range and my domain.

So, I looked at the answer back of the book it says Range is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and Domain is $\wp(\mathbb{Z}_5)$. And this is where I am confused why $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ what notation is being used because integer modulus isn't being used at all. And why the domain is the power set of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: What is meant by a backslash then a z then subscript 5?

Comment: it is Z (Integer set)_5

Comment: So same as $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ right? If so your A consists of ordered pairs, first element a subset of thatm second element the count of that subset.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ is correct. What you seem to be misunderstanding is that although we are dealing with $\Bbb{Z}_5$ here, it is neither the domain nor the range of this function.

Our function takes in *any* subset of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ and outputs the **cardinality** of that subset. The set of all subsets of a given set is defined to be the **power set** of that given set. This function doesn't input numbers. It inputs sets. It outputs a number.

Now why is the range $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$? Recall what our function is doing. It takes in a subset and it outputs its cardinality. Perhaps if you give it some thought you may be able to answer this question on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of $A$: $A=\{\langle X,|X|\rangle:X\color{red}{\subseteq}\Bbb Z_5\}$. It’s a set of ordered pairs whose first elements are the **subsets** of $\Bbb Z_5$, not the **elements** of $\Bbb Z_5$. In other words, the domain of $A$ is indeed $\wp(\Bbb Z_5)$. The range is the set of all possible values of $|X|$ for subsets $X$ of $\Bbb Z_5$. $|X|$ is the cardinality of $X$, the number of elements that it has; since $\Bbb Z_5$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and therefore has $5$ elements, its subsets can have any number of elements from $0$ through $5$. Thus, the range of $A$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Finally, $\Bbb Z_5$ here is being treated simply as the set of non-negative integers less than $5$; I suspect that somewhere in the book $\Bbb Z_n$ is defined as $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ or the equivalent. In any case, no arithmetic of any kind is being done with these elements.

Comment: I am still "kinda" lost of the range explanation. 
I do get the |X| has 5 elements. 
I am confused on,"its subsets can have any number of elements from 0 through 5."

Comment: @user1981: Consider the subsets $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$, $\{0,1\}$, $\{0,1,2\}$, $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$: they have $0,1,2,3,4$, and $5$ elements, respectively. No subset of $\Bbb Z_5$ can have more than $5$ elements, since $\Bbb Z_5$ itself has only $5$.